# Connect vs code to tfs on local server

Tags: tfs, angular6, visual-studio-code, azure-repos

I'm trying to connect tfs ,I did these steps:

1. Install vsc
2. Install Azure Repo
3. Install Check out tfs file

and this is my setting.json codes

```
   {
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true,
    "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.enabled": false,
    "checkouttfs.tflocation": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
    "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light"
}
```

but when I click team -> signin I get this error:

> (team) The configured version of TF does not meet the minimum
>   version. You may run into errors or limitations with certain commands
>   until you upgrade. Minimum version: 14.102.0

Now what should I do? 
my tf version is 1.0.1
my vsc version is 1.30

Comment: Why do you think your tf version is 1.0.1?  (tf versions are tied to the Visual Studio version, so there was never a 1.0.1, versioning started at TFS 2015 (8.0), so I think you’re looking at a different version number.)

Comment: @EdwardThomson the tfs plugin that add in vs code has just two version that they are 1.0.0 and 1.0.1.

Comment: The error message is the tfs plugin complaining about your TFS client version.  What version of Visual Studio and/or the TFS client tools do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue for connect vs code to tfs you should install visual studio 2017 or later. my visual studio was 2015 and the vesrion of tf.exe was down.

Answer (score 0):

## Your next steps would be:

4. Download Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 at https://code.visualstudio.com/Download.
5. After the program finishes installing for a few hours, this will update your TF.exe to a version of at least 15.129.#####
6. Then update your setting.json to
   "tfvc.location": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe",

   OR

   "tfvc.location": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe",
   "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true,

Finally you will no longer see the following error message:   "(team) The configured version of TF does not meet the minimum version. You may run into errors or limitations with certain commands until you upgrade. Minimum version: 14.102.0"